# grep missing line when comparing two files

Tags: awk, grep

I have two huge files

data.txt (containing like 1324 lines of email substring)

```
test
test1
test3
test4
test6
test7
test9
test10
```

values.txt (containing like 2221 lines of email : this is containing the 1324 lines from the previous)

```
test@gmail.com
test1@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
test4@gmail.com
test6@gmail.com
test7@gmail.com
test9@gmail.com
test10@gmail.com
test74@gmail.com
test14@gmail.com
test34@gmail.com
test44@gmail.com
test64@gmail.com
test74@gmail.com
```

All is working as intended the problem that I should have a file containing 897 lines of email, what I'm having is 874 lines of email.

So there's 23 lines that are missing and I don't know how to locate them.
Maybe it's a problem with my function ?

```
grep -v -f data.txt values.txt > result.txt
```

Is there a way to do it with grep maybe ?

expected result.txt

```
test74@gmail.com
test14@gmail.com
test34@gmail.com
test44@gmail.com
test64@gmail.com
test74@gmail.com
```

Comment: ``comm -1 <(sort data.txt) <(values.txt) > only_in_data` might help you. Use -2 and change output to `only_in_values`. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have substring matches, where `data.txt` contains `test1` and is matched for `test10@gmail.com`? If so, try adding `-w` to the grep options to require full word matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Considering that you want to get common ids in both the files.

```
awk '
FNR == NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
!($1 in arr)
' data.txt  FS="@" values.txt
```

Output will be as follows:

```
test74@gmail.com
test14@gmail.com
test34@gmail.com
test44@gmail.com
test64@gmail.com
test74@gmail.com
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR == NR{                       ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when data.txt is being read.
  arr[$0]                        ##Creating arr with index of current line.
  next                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!($1 in arr)                     ##Checking condition if 1st column is NOT present in arr then print line.
' data.txt  FS="@" values.txt    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: I updated my question with the desired result

Comment: @Taieb, ohhh, I had tested this solution successfully with your shown samples, please see my answer I have updated the sample output in my answer, let me know on same, thank you.

Comment: NOW it's working as intended, many thanks for the explanation, much appreciated. have a great day.